# Fragments and setting up OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a project with Fragments. On the main Fragment I have a list with items (pic related), which is generated by using a custom adapter and I think I need to use the OnItemClickListener to make clicking on items going to another activity. Below is a fragment of my HomeFragment class, and here is where I want to create an OnItemClickListener, is it possible? How can I do that?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        RowBean RowBean_data[] = new RowBean[]{
                new RowBean(R.drawable.kamil, "Kamil "),
                new RowBean(R.drawable.bartlomiej, "Bartlomiej "),
                new RowBean(R.drawable.krzysztof, "Krzysztof ")
        };


        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_style, RowBean_data);
        ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {        super.onAttach(activity);    }

    @Override    public void onDetach() {        super.onDetach();    }

    @Override    public void onClick(View v) {      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    }

}
```

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following listener before `return rootView;` statement in your `onCreateView` method

```
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                 //do stuff
                 Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,AnotherActivty.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to use `onItemClickListener()`
You can use it in following way :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
            // You can launch activity here in your case.
    }
});
```